# Como somar os valores de uma coluna SQL

Tags: php, sql, pdo

Preciso fazer um sistema que pegue os três maiores doadores.

Minha tabela:

```
donate_ID | donate_NAME | donate_AMOUNT
```

Este `donate_NAME` pode se repetir, e caso  isso aconteça seu valor vai somar com os outros, porém o que deve ser somado é o `donate_AMOUNT`.

Não consegui chegar a essa lógica.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o [Group By](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html) para agrupar os valores no SQL e o [SUM](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum) para somar os valores agrupados.

```
SELECT donate_id, 
       donate_name, 
       Sum(donate_amount) AS donate_AMOUNT 
FROM   donate 
GROUP  BY donate_name 
ORDER  BY donate_amount DESC;
```